# How to get latest development release info of Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

How can I get the latest development release info of Ubuntu?

For example, `do-release-upgrade --devel-release` will upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10 right now:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '23.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

**How can I know if this is alpha, beta, or point release?**

This situation is less clear when it's Mid-October of 2023, where it may be either 23.10 beta or 23.10 final.

Comment: @guiverc that only answers how to upgrade to a development release, not _which_ release it is.

Comment: Ubuntu *mantic* will upgrade normally if your sources are correct and you apply all upgrades (*this may require `sudo apt full-upgrade` and more than normal `apt upgrade`).  There is no difference between *alpha*, *beta* or post-beta (we're post-beta now) and no point releases, and it reaches RC or *release candidate* very close; where Ubuntu *mantic* will change to say Ubuntu 23.10 in the final days before release. There maybe many *final* images ith the actual final being the last *RC* that gets moved to the release ISO/image. The terms *beta*, RC, or *final* relate really to ISOs

Comment: @guiverc is it not true that there are more testers/bug reports after each alpha, beta, or release candidate announcement? I do not need complete stability (hence why I want to try beta), but I also do not want my system crashing on reboot (which I would expect is more likely to happen on a nightly release). If there is no distinction between those terms, how do you know it's post-beta now?

Comment: If I use `lsb_release -d` on my system (*I sit on development*) it'll currently report `Description:    Ubuntu Mantic Minotaur (development branch)` which will only change as RC is reached; when the `base-files` package is updated to show we've reached *Release Candidate*.  The system then becomes Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: Night release?  There can be many *dailies* created in a 24 hour period; they're created as required (*4 in a day the most I recall thus far this cycle; thus the ISO reached .3*) If you look at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/446/builds you'll see the current daily & note we've already had 2 for one product/architecture. I'll suggest there are bug reports most of the cycle; yes there is a increase late in the *alpha* & early *beta* stages, but not that I think of as significant change. You can view them be reported on IRC etc. When installed, the system can be used ~normally.

Comment: FYI:  We call the ISOs *dailies* as it's a simple term, a more accurate term maybe *interval* as the cron job is often set to create them one per week early in the *development* cycle for some products, most of the cycle they'll be set to run once per day (*time of run staggered so the build machine isn't clogged with all builds/architectures running at the same time!*), but any *product manager* can login & cause an unscheduled build to occur.. which is done when required; thus why there can be many builds (.1 added to YYYYMMDD build for 2nd build on that date, .2 for 3rd build etc..)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the latest release information from the following:

- The Ubuntu Blog: https://ubuntu.com/blog
- The Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/uwn/124
- The Ubuntu Developer mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel
- Many teams publish weekly summaries of their work at https://discourse.ubuntu.com

There is no requirement to use these platforms; discussion about development and testing can be many places. Use these as starting points to find a community that matches your interests.

For 23.10 specifically, the release calendar details freezes, betas, and other details: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989

Answer (score 0):

At https://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/, navigate to the last number (for example, `23.10`).

- If there is a `release/`, it is a final release.
- If there is a `beta/`, it is a beta.
- If there are only `.` and `..`, it is alpha.